# How to override super constructor

Tags: java, templates

I extends a super class which has a template parameter TService:

```
public abstract class SupplySideServer<TService extends SupplySideService, TRequest extends Request, TResponse extends Response> {

protected TService service;

public SupplySideServer(TService service) {
    this.service = service;
}
```

I've a subclass:

```
public class SupplySideServerImpl<TService extends SupplySideService, TRequest extends Request, TResponse extends Response> {

//public SupplySideServerImpl(Class<? extends SupplySideService<T>> service) {
    public SupplySideServerImpl(TService service) {
    super(service);
}
```

but it won't compile, how do I pass service to the subclass? Do I have to use the template parameters in the subclass as from the super/abstract classes?

Comment: Seems like you forgot `extends SupplySideServer` in class declaration.

Comment: you cant override constructor, you can only call it

Comment: public class SupplySideServerImpl<TService extends SupplySideService, TRequest extends Request, TResponse extends Response> extends SupplySideServer  {

Comment: This is the error:  - SupplySideServer is a raw type. References to generic type SupplySideServer<TService,TRequest,TResponse> should be 
  parameterized

Comment: Doesn't seem like an error to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your sub class **SupplySideServerImpl** did not extend the parent class **SupplySideServer**. Due to this the compiler thinks that your sub class **SupplySideServerImpl** is implicitly extending only the **Object** class (as we know that every class in Java extends Object class). As the **Object** class's default constructor is a no-arg constructor, your call to the super class constructor should have no arguments. I think the below change in your code should work. Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
public class SupplySideServerImpl<TService extends SupplySideService, TRequest extends Request, TResponse extends Response> extends SupplySideServer<TService extends SupplySideService, TRequest extends Request, TResponse extends Response>{

        public SupplySideServerImpl(TService service) {
        super(service);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't allow it:  - Syntax error on token "SupplySideServer", { expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

Comment: I didn't use it with the typo, the above error is same after.

Comment: Could you update your code(entire could would be helpful) and also include the whole error line you got.

Comment: I made it compiled by extends the typed param only in the implementing class.